# How read HTTP raw POST data in PHP

Tags: php, raw-post

The remote server periodically queries to my PHP page via HTTP HEAD (check only KeepAlive - this works). If the remote server registers a trigger, sends me the XML format with the data (in POST raw format). I can not find where the mistake is or information on how I can read the input data.

I try this (no error show), but the result is empty.

```
ini_set('always_populate_raw_post_data', 'On');

$data1 = file_get_contents('php://input');
//var_dump($data1); //NULL
fwrite($fp, 'php://input: ' . serialize($data1) . "\n");

$data2 = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
//var_dump($data2); //NULL
fwrite($fp, 'GLOBALS HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA: ' . serialize($data2) . "\n");

$data3 = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
//var_dump($data3); //NULL
fwrite($fp, 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA: ' . serialize($data3) . "\n");

//print_r($_POST); //NULL
fwrite($fp, 'POST: ' . serialize($_POST) . "\n");


$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);
fwrite($fp, 'BETA: ' . $xmlData . "\n");
```

Result in log file:

```
HeadRequest at 2015-01-21 23:35:47
======================================================
php://input: s:0:"";
GLOBALS HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA: N;
HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA: N;
POST: a:0:{}
BETA:
```

About server: PHP version is 5.5.9, Server run on Linux (Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: A HEAD request has no POST data …

Comment: Did you use `fopen` first for `$fp`?

Comment: Yes, I use fopen etc. - here I add only all methods, which I try for read values from HTTP RAW POST.

Comment: HEAD request is only KeepAlive. If the remote server registers a trigger, sends me xml format with the data (in post raw format).

Comment: Can you try by  suppressing the error by adding @file_get_contents('php://input');

Answer (score 4):

I got it and give a more complex solution.

Result (working code):

```
<?php
    // Validate read-only stream for read raw data from the request body
    if(file_get_contents('php://input')=='')
    {
        // Throw exception
    }
    else
    {
        // Get read-only stream for read raw data from the request body
        $strRequest = file_get_contents('php://input');

        // Import request to XML structure
        $DOMDocumentRequest = new DOMDocument;
        $DOMDocumentRequest->loadXML($strRequest);
    }
?>
```

About a problem:

- If I run code on [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) ([Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) LTS (Trusty Tahr)), it doesn’t work
- If I run code on LAMP (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and install [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) with Pcap, the server crashed - I must reinstall Apache 2
- If I run code on [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) ([Windows Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 x64 with [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)), all is right

Comment: Do not just automatically use data from php://input without some form of filtering and validation. Ideally, you would also perform a UTF-8 encoding check first by using a stream filter. Also, you should be url decoding the data you from php://input before using it. Otherwise, you may not get the data the way it was intended to be represented. With $_POST, the url decoding has already taken place!